# Create a list with the common elements of other lists in C#

Tags: c#, list, merge

I know how merge lists, but if I only want the common objects?

Example:

```
List A={1,2,3,4,5}
List B={4,5,6}
```

I know how to create this list

```
List C={1,2,3,4,5,4,5,6}
```

but I want to create this

```
List C={4,5}
```

Comment: What language is this? It doesn't look like C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq and the `Intersect` method:

```cs
C = A.Intersect(B)
```